# Manipulating Data with R

Tags: r, split, duplicates

I am trying to collate hundreds of (excel) files with many rows and columns into one large data set. I was able to write a code to collate the files into one. However, I am stuck with cleaning up of data. In particular, I have the following roadblocks

1. Many (not all) of the files have duplicate columns - currently R is keeping all the columns and appending `X.1`, `X.2` and so on after the duplicated column. How do I stop R from reading the duplicate column and move to the next column?
2. I stopped R from inputting a dot in the column names by setting `check.names = F`. I then replaced the space with _. Now the tricky part is I want to split each column into 4 columns - For ex. `X_1%_2/2/2012:P` is my column name and it has data in it (`NA`, blanks and other data). How do I create 4 columns out of it such that I have `X 1% 2/2/2012 P` as 4 different columns with original data under `P` column and other 3 as blank columns?

Below is my code for reference (it isnt the most efficient code but its my first R code - I have a long way to go...)

```
# I am using XLConnect package so far


data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xls")
df = readWorksheetFromFile(file=data.files[1], sheet=1, check.names=F) # Read the first     file

# Loop through the remaining files and merge them to the existing data frame
for (file in data.files[-1]) {
newFile = readWorksheetFromFile(file=file, sheet=1, check.names=F)
df = merge(df, newFile, all = TRUE, check.names=F)
}

write.csv(df, file="read_1.csv")

#Deleting some unwanted columns
temp = df
temp = df[,-agrep("Mty", colnames(df))]
df = temp
temp = df[,-agrep("Dur", colnames(df))]
df = temp

#Replacing spaces in the column names with underscores
names(df) <- sub(" ", "_", names(df))
names(df) <- sub(" ", "_", names(df))

write.csv(df, file="read_1.csv") #writing output in CSV
```

Below is the `dput(head(df))` output.. (I deleted a lot of data to get a concise output)...

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1373259600, 1373346000, 1373432400, 
1373518800, 1373605200, 1373864400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), `AA_5.55_02/01/2017:Price` = c(105.57574, 105.63598, 
105.70395, 106.62471, 106.49467, 106.62642), `AA_6.5_06/15/2018:Price` = c(106.75947, 
106.84083, 107.248726, 108.383835, 108.39564, 108.3026), `AA_5.72_02/23/2019:Price` = c(101.00432, 
101.09463, 101.67893, 102.75101, 103.0618, 103.267204), `AAL_6.125_06/01/2018:Price` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `AAL_5.25_01/31/2021:Price` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `AAL_4.95_01/15/2023:Price` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `AALLN_2.625_04/03/2017:Price` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `AALLN_2.625_09/27/2017:Price` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `AALLN_9.375_04/08/2019:Price` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("Date", 
"AA_5.55_02/01/2017:Price", "AA_6.5_06/15/2018:Price", "AA_5.72_02/23/2019:Price", 
"AAL_6.125_06/01/2018:Price", "AAL_5.25_01/31/2021:Price", "AAL_4.95_01/15/2023:Price", 
"AALLN_2.625_04/03/2017:Price", "AALLN_2.625_09/27/2017:Price", 
"AALLN_9.375_04/08/2019:Price"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: A `dput(head(df))` might contributors see enough of the data to get a better feel for how to help.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying. Could you please elaborate - as in should I share more information? or should I try using dput?

Comment: Does this use an installed package?  If so, please state it in the post.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(df))`

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat - Have edited the post to include the package used and the dput(head(df)) output.. Please let me know if there are any suggestions that I can try..